# Подскажите нормальный способ запустить из веба долгую фоновую операцию в .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, background

Пусть у меня есть веб приложение .NET MVC. На странице есть кнопка "Запустить пересчет". Вызывается экшен контроллера. Экшен контроллера вызывает некий сервис, который выполняет очень долгий пересчет, оперируя данными из базы. Понятно дело, что вызывать эту логику из какого либо сервиса в экшене - так себе идея. Просто получим истечения ожидания времени ответа от сервера и на этом все кончится. А можно как то запустить, и пойти "по своим делам"? На другие страницы, я имею в виду. Еще было бы здорово иметь возможность посмотреть, доработало оно или нет. Выводить что нибудь в веб я имею в виду.

Единственный вариант, который мне пришел в голову - это создать Hosted service, где первым делом обращаться к базе, к специальной таблице, где стоит флаг - начинать пересчет или нет. Как только нажата кнопка "Запустить пересчет", этот флаг ставится в true, а хостед сервис при следующей итерации вызывает эту самую долгую логику пересчета. Как то аналогично, думаю, можно поступить и с банером "Пересчет работает" для веба.

Но есть ли способ с меньшим числом телодвижений? То что я тут рассказал, я имею в виду с базой и флагами в базе и с хостед сервсиом - это велосипед?

Comment: Сделать метод перерасчета, который дернет сервис, который в свою очередь сразу вернет управление обратно с некоторым guid, перед этим в отдельном потоке запустив задачу. После этого сделать метод Ping к этому методу и по этому гуид трекать статус

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо за комментарий. Правильно понял, что как любую долгую фоновую задачу, мы стартуем Перерасчет в отдельном потоке? Не понял про guid. Как понять "вернет управление обратно с некоторым guid". Этот Guid он к чему привязан? Это id потока? Где мне его сохранить? Ведь http - стейтлес. Я уйду со страницы и все. В сессии?

Comment: Да, в отдельном потоке что бы не занимать поток asp.net. Создается какой-то guid и возвращается на фронт. Потом фронт этот guid передает в метод ping, который чекает по нему задачу, которая привязана по нему. Где хранить список таких guid? Можно хранить в статическом классе, а лучше в бд.

Comment: Задача после выполнения сделает запись в базе, в какой-то лог делает запись, что закончила работу с своим ид. Метод пинг будет смотреть эту базу. Если задача не очень большая и выполняется за меньше чем 5 минут можно хранить в статическом классе. Нужно так же добавить очистку всех этих данных, если метод пинг не вызывался для этого ид N количество времени.